# Doctrine returning only one result which possibly violating where statement

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `Item` and `Property` with **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne** relations.

### Item.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository")
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("NOTIFY")
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Item
    ...
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Property", mappedBy="item")
     */
    protected $itemProperties;   

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdTs", type="datetime")
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $createdTs;
    ...
```

### Property.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 */
class Property
    ...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Item
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="itemProperties")
     */
    private $item;
    ...
```

I want get all **items** older than `$date` which have **no property entities** where `type` has value invisible.

I build a query like this:

```php
/**
 * @param \Datetime $date
 * @return array
 */
public function getVisibleItemsOlderThan(\Datetime $date)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('i')
        ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
        ->join('i.properties', 'p')
        ->where($qb->expr()->lt('i.createdTs', ':date'))
        ->andWhere('p.type <> :type')
        ->setParameters([
            'date' => $date,
            'type' => 'invisible'
        ]);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This query returning me **one** Item, which properties has field where value of `type` is *invisible* ignoring rest of items in database.

Comment: Have you tried a leftJoin instead of a join in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this will work, although there may be a better way.

```
/**
 * @param \Datetime $date
 * @return array
 */
public function getVisibleItemsOlderThan(\Datetime $date)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('i')
        ->from('AppBundle:Item', 'i')
        ->leftJoin('i.properties', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.type = :type')
        ->where($qb->expr()->lt('i.createdTs', ':date'))
        ->andWhere('p.id IS NULL')
        ->setParameters([
            'date' => $date,
            'type' => 'invisible'
        ]);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

You may find `andWhere('i.properties IS EMPTY')` works here too.